I get Py4JJerror when updating Parquet files (append new values to old tables) in Azure Synapse Notebook
I am trying to update a Parquet file in Azure Synapse, by performing a union with a new one, removing the duplicates, copying all that to a new dataframe then overwriting the old one. All work fine until the last line, but when the code reaches the last line i get Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4368.save.  and i cannot understand why. Here is the code:
source_file = 'abfss://synapse@storag.dfs.core.windows.net/ingest/sales_*'
destination_dir = 'abfss://synapse@storag.dfs.core.windows.net/ingest/parquet/sales/'

df = spark.read.csv(source_file)
existing_file = spark.read.parquet(destination_dir)
combined = existing_file.union(df)
final = combined.select("*").dropDuplicates()
final.write.mode('overwrite').format('parquet').save(destination_dir)

